# how to execute a javascript function on closing browser but not on page referesh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Actually I want to delete a localstorage key on closing the browser for which i'm using jquery unload but at the same time i dont want to execute that function when some one refresh the page?

how can i achieve that?

Comment: You generally can't achieve that, at least not reliably, as there's no way to know if the value was deleted from storage or not before the browser closed, and you can halt the browser closing either.

Comment: ok so i think i have to use cookie instead where i can set a time limit atleast :(

Comment: You could just use [**SessionStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) if persistency only in a session is what you want

Comment: @adeneo thanks for letting me know about this :)